# NativeScript border-radius for UI element is not working

Tags: css, telerik, nativescript, visual-studio-extensions, angular2-nativescript

I am using the VS telerik extension to develop my mobile application. However, I am trying to curve the borders of my UI elements by using CSS border-radius:3px-52px and it is not working. I have used several methods to resolve it, but non actually worked. I assume it is a bug with the VS telerik extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `px` in border-radius value. Just use a number value.

Comment: I am also having problem with using:     
border-bottom-left-radius:10; 
It is not working with or without px

Comment: I'm not sure specific border sides are supported. You should check the docs and/or source code to see if they are.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a class to the image then remove the px it should work.

Example

```
.avatar{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 150;
    width: 100
  }

<Image src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/677158239851646976/l-mkCSMK.jpg"  class="avatar"></Image>
```